# Creating HDF5 from rgb images matlab

Tags: matlab, hdf5, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I intend to feed my test and train images to caffe through hdf5. But before that some pre-processing is required, below is my hdf5 conversion code. My images are already 256*256.

```
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
function X = hdf5_preparation(file,numberOfImages)
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------

file_list = fopen(file);
X=zeros(227,227,3,numberOfImages);
d = load('ilsvrc_2012_mean');
IMAGE_MEAN = d.image_mean;
IMAGE_DIM = 256;
CROPPED_DIM = 227;

for i=1:numberOfImages
    image = fgetl(file_list);
    im = imread(image);
    im = single(im);
    im = im(:,:,[3 2 1]) - IMAGE_MEAN;
    center = 15;
    im = im(center:center+CROPPED_DIM-1,center:center+CROPPED_DIM-1,:)
    im = permute(im, [2 1 3]);
    X(:,:,:,i)=im;
end
```

---

And then, 
`hdf5write('my_data.h5', '/X',X);`

I am not sure about the correctness of this method. Please help! (Also I am not doing oversampling here, as I don't know how to handle that in hdf5.)

Comment: looks ok to me. what is the question here?

Comment: I was not sure that it was completely correct, anyway here suppose if I do oversampling then I will have 10 crops, i.e; 227*227*3*10, then how do i handle that for hdf5?

Comment: And also the cropping which I am doing, just the centre crop, (while caffe uses random cropping,) is it correct?

Comment: if you oversample, then you'll have more examples, you should add more labels and other features you want to train.